# How to deploy nodejs(express) application to vercel?

Tags: node.js, express, deployment, vercel

I'm trying to upload Nodejs application which has MVC structure to Vercel. But I'm not getting expected output. I've seen many similar questions on this site but none of them has answers else have different issues.
Here is the structure of the project

```
- .env
- .gitattributes
- .gitignore
- app.js
- app_api
  - config
    - passport.js
  - controllers
    - authentication.js
    - dist
      - authentication.dev.js
      - find_ctrl.dev.js
      - main.dev.js
    - find_ctrl.js
    - main.js
    - prflctlr.js
  - models
    - db.js
    - dist
      - db.dev.js
      - fantom.dev.js
      - fantommini.dev.js
      - profile.dev.js
      - reports.dev.js
      - user.dev.js
    - fantom.js
    - fantommini.js
    - message.js
    - profile.js
    - reports.js
  - routes
    - dist
      - index.dev.js
    - index.js
- app_server
  - controllers
    - dist
      - main.dev.js
      - posts.dev.js
    - main.js
    - posts.js
    - prflctlr.js
    - sign.js
  - routes
    - dist
      - index.dev.js
    - index.js
    - users.js
  - views
    - alanrep.pug
    - chapter.pug
    - chapterPost.pug
    - dist
      - alanrep.html
      - chapter.html
      - dream-post.html
      - forum.html
      - home.html
      - layout.html
      - profile.html
      - settings.html
    - draft_fmini.pug
    - draft_home.pug
    - draft_layout.pug
    - dream-post.pug
    - error.pug
    - find.pug
    - fmDl.pug
    - fmini.pug
    - home.pug
    - home2.pug
    - info.pug
    - layout.pug
    - message.pug
    - messages.pug
    - notifications.pug
    - profile.pug
    - settings.pug
    - signin.pug
    - signup.pug
    - signup2.pug
    - test.html
    - user_profile.pug
- bin
  - www
- bugs.txt
- dist
  - app.dev.js
- jargons.txt
- package-lock.json
- package.json
- public
  - images
    - no_result.png
    - search1.png
    - user-account-management-logo-user-icon-11562867145a56rus2zwu.png
  - javascripts
    - 404.js
    - comein.js
    - converter.html
    - dist
      - dreampost.dev.js
      - find.dev.js
      - fmini.dev.js
      - home.dev.js
      - layout.dev.js
      - settings.dev.js
    - dreampost.js
    - emoji.js
    - find.js
    - fmini.js
    - home.js
    - layout.js
    - message.js
    - profile.js
    - settings.js
    - token.js
    - usrDefined.js
  - stylesheets
    - 404.css
    - alenrep.css
    - chapter.css
    - comein.css
    - dist
      - sample.css
    - draft_style.css
    - dreampost.css
    - emoji.css
    - explore.css
    - fantom.css
    - find.css
    - fmini.css
    - home.css
    - home2.css
    - layout.css
    - message.css
    - messages.css
    - profile.css
    - sample.css
    - sample.css.map
    - sample.sass
    - settings.css
    - style.css
- README.md
- vercel.json
```

Here is package.json

```
{
  "name": "dreamt",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "app.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "18.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
      // dependencies
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp-header": "^2.0.9"
  }
}
```

## Attempts to solve error

Here is vercel.json

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
      {
        "src": "app.js",
        "use": "@vercel/node"
      }
    ],
    "routes": [
      {
        "src": "/(.*)",
        "dest": "/"
      }
    ]
  }
```

here is app.js

```
var express = require('express');
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

require('./app_api/models/db')
require('./app_api/config/passport')

var indexRouter = require('./app_server/routes/index');
var apiRouter = require('./app_api/routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./app_server/routes/users');

var app = express();
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname,'app_server', 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use('/api', (req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With,Content-Type, Accept,Authorization');
 next();
 });
 app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Content-Type, Accept,Authorization');
 next();
 });
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/api', apiRouter)


// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});
const uri = "database url?";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
client.connect(err => {
  client.close();
});
module.exports = app;
```

What mistake am I doing.
vercel runtime log simply shows 404 error. Sometimes

```
Error: Cannot find module './base64-vlq'
```

Here is [webapp address](https://dreamverse.vercel.app/). Is there any error on port?. How to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was wrong. I was trying to deploy a full stack nodejs application in vercel but that is for frontend. Now I deployed it in render.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).